# Доступ к содержимому массива и 3 класса

Tags: java

Всем привет.

Вопрос, как достучаться до массива?

У меня при обращении из класса A я получаю длину массива 0, хотя он заполняется на больше чем 100 элементов.
Если вывести содержимое из класса С, пока он его заполняет, то он покажет все содержимое,

```
Class A {
   B b = new B();
   C c = new C();

   public static void main(){
      b.doSmth();
      System.out.print(c.getArrayList());
   }
}

Class B {
   C c=new C();
   c.setArrayList(String s);
}

Class C {
  private ArrayList list=new ArrayList();

  setArrayList(String s){
      list.add(s);
  }

  getArrayList(){
      return list.size();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас создается два разных объекта класса `C`, поэтому массив пустой.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
public class A {
    B b;

    A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void method() {
        b.method();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
       C c = new C();
       B b = new B(c);
       A a = new A(b);

       a.method();
       System.out.println(a.b.c.getArrayList());
    }   
}


class B {
    C c;

    public B(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    void method() {
        c.setArrayList("hello");
    }
}


class C {
    private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    public void setArrayList(String s) {
        list.add(s);
    }

    public int getArrayList() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Вообще не очень хорошая композиция классов, вам нужно лучше о ней подумать.

Comment: Прошу прощения за неточность в вопросе. От статик я отказался, это самый простой вариант, но я хочу от него отказаться

Comment: этот код будет так же работать и без статиков, но создание объектов придется задащить в main. т.к. нестатические поля из статического метода как известно не доступны.

Comment: Так, а тут начинаются сложности. Так как этот пример, конечно же, является упрощенным вариантом.

На самом деле, у меня класс A, вызывает класс B, который вызывает С, в котором формируется массив, получая данные из класса C, а затем, следующим пунктом у меня в классе А вызывается класс D, куда суется информация из массива из класса C.
Т.е. примерно так

A->B->C;
A->D->getArray(C).

То есть, используя ваш пример, мне необходимо в метод вставить что-то типа

    class A {

Comment: class A {
   
     public static void main() {
     B b = new B();
     C c = new C();
     D d = new D();

        d.doSmth(b.doSmth.c.getArray());
        System.out.print(c.getArrayList());
    }
}
Как-то так... или я даже представить не могу

Comment: @Dred изменил ответ

Comment: так, теперь все классы статичны? )

Comment: можешь убрать static  у классов, а метод main запихнуть в класс A.

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу переделать. Вернее я могу, но не вижу смысла куда еще более переделывать. Ранее было 5 классов, где 5-ый был статичный

Comment: Так, как это сложно))) Спасибо. попробую...)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Получилось сделать так:

Class A {
  

   public static void main(){
      B b = new B();
      C c = new C();
      b.doSmth();
      System.out.print(c.getArrayList());
   }
}

Class B {
 C c;  
 
B(C c){
    this.c=c;
}
  
   c.setArrayList(String s);
}

Class C {
  private ArrayList list=new ArrayList();

 private setArrayList(String s){
      list.add(s);
  }

public int  getArrayList(){
      return list.size();
  }
}